# Text in a file replaced by regex. How to write the change into file?

Tags: python, regex

I can change the text in a file line by line, but I don't know how to write the results (changes) into the file.

This is a small part of my file:

```
<name>2016-09-15_obere-firstalm_gehen-6,5km</name>
<extensions>
    <line xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/gpx_style/0/2">
        <color>000000</color>
    </line>
</extensions>
<trkseg>
    <trkpt lat="47.671193" lon="11.886518">
        <ele>1115.6</ele>
        <time>2016-09-15T11:57:44Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="47.670686" lon="11.886412">
        <ele>1117.6</ele>
        <time>2016-09-15T11:58:14Z</time>
    </trkpt>
    <trkpt lat="47.670821" lon="11.886459">
        <ele>1055.6</ele>
        <time>2016-09-15T11:58:44Z</time>
    </trkpt>
```

With a Python script I change values of elevations by adding 30.
Example:
    Before change:
    elevation (ele) 1115.6,
    after change:
    elevation (ele) 1145.6

```
#This little Python adds 30 to elevation:
import re
f1 = raw_input("name of your GPX file: ")
f1 = open(f1,'r+')
for line in f1:
res = re.search(r"<(ele)>(.+)</\1>",line)
if res:
    number=float(res.group(2))
    number_elev=number+30
    number_elev=str(number_elev)
    ress = re.sub(r"<(ele)>(.+)", r"\2",number_elev)
    #print shows correct new values between <ele> and </ele>
    print ress + "\n"
    ###but how to write into the gpx file these changes?
f1.close()
print "OK"
```

Expected: Write the file with the changed lines.
Actual: I don't know how to write a change by regexp into the file.
Thx in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to google about how to write to file in Python?

Comment: Applications almost never 'change something in a file'. They replace the old file with a new file. There are two ways to go here: 1: You read the entire file into memory, close the file handle, manipulate the data, and then overwrite the file. 2: You write out all lines from the old file (both the original and changed ones) to a temporary file and at the end delete the input file and rename the temporary file to the name of the inputfile.

Comment: You can use Python libraries that works with XML, it is a better solution than using re library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll first need to read all the lines in your file and write each one to the file replacing the ones matching the regex search.
Also since one more `<ele>..</ele>` tag sequences can be on the same line, you'll need to find all occurrences of those in the line and replace them accordingly.

```
import re
f1 = raw_input("name of your GPX file: ")
with open(f1,'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open(f1, 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        ress = line
        res = re.findall(r"<(ele)>(.+)</\1>",ress)
        if res:
            for r in res:
                number=float(r[1])
                number_elev=number+30
                number_elev=str(number_elev)
                ress=re.sub(r"<(ele)>{}</(ele)>".format(r[1]), r"<ele>{}</ele>".format(number_elev),string=ress, count=1)
        f.write(ress)
```

Comment: It runs ok. I only revised  two little things: two different files for read and write, and in the line next to last: </ele> instead of <\ele>
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to read and write from/to the same file at the same time. Just create and output file and write to it.

The following code is untested but it should work.

```
import re
f1 = input("name of your GPX file: ")
input_file = open(f1,'r+')
output_file = open(f1 + '_output', 'w+')
for line in input_file:
    res = re.search(r"<(ele)>(.+)</\1>", line)
    if res:
        number=float(res.group(2))
        number_elev=number+30
        number_elev=str(number_elev)
        line = line.replace(res.group(2), number_elev)
    output_file.write(line)
input_file.close()
output_file.close()
print("OK")
```

Comment: It runs ok, too. I changed only a little bit: f1=raw_input(...........)
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file all at once and apply the regex to the data and write out the modified data to another file as follows:

```
import re

with open('input-file.xml') as fd:
    data = fd.read()

regex = re.compile('(<ele>)([\d.]+)(</ele>)')
while True:
    match = regex.search(data)
    if not match:
        break
    new_value = float(match.group(2)) + 30
    # <ele>6373.8</ele> becomes </ele>6373.8<ele> so that it doesnt match again
    data = regex.sub(r'\g<3>{}\g<1>'.format(new_value), data, count=1)

# undo </ele>...<ele> the tag reversal done inside the while loop
regex = re.compile('(</ele>)([\d.]+)(<ele>)')
data = regex.sub(r'\3\2\1', data)

with open('output-file.xml', 'w') as fd:
    fd.write(data)
```

Comment: It runs ok, too. Thank you very much !